# Route Name for Conventions-Based Routing

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using conventions-based routing (as opposed to attribute-based routing) using ASP.NET CORE 3. I know it is possible to get the chosen route name when using attribute-based routing by using the `AttributeRouteInfo.Name` property. How do I do the same when using conventions-based routing (by this I mean setting up the routes in Startup.cs)? I can't find any explanation or properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I found to do it is like this, and it works with *both* attribute routing and conventional routing. Put this in the controller's action method:

```
Endpoint endpoint = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;
String routeName = endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<RouteNameMetadata>().RouteName;
```

This technique does not require you to add custom objects to the `MapControllerRoute()` as in [Zhi Lv's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66561565/314944).

Comment: Yes, you are right, this method is more concise and effective. Congratulation!

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I assume your application is an Asp.net Core MVC application, and in the `Startup.Configure` method, you are using the `MapControllerRoute()` or `MapAreaControllerRoute()` method to set the conventional route, like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

And at present, you want to get the route name ("default") in the controller method, right?

If that is the case, as a workaround, you could use the [MapControllerRoute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.controllerendpointroutebuilderextensions.mapcontrollerroute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [MapAreaControllerRoute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.controllerendpointroutebuilderextensions.mapareacontrollerroute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) method's `defaults` parameter to store the route name.

For example:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {  
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default route",
                pattern: "{controller=Reports}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
                new { routeName= "default route" }); //add the routeName.
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            
        });
```

Then, in the controller method, you could get the value from the `ControllerContext.RouteData`, like this:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    { 
        var contenxt = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values;
        if (contenxt.Keys.Contains("routeName"))
        { 
            var routename = contenxt["routeName"];
        } 
        return View();
    }
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]